# XLConnect saveWorkbook function can't write workbook object to disk

Tags: r, xlconnect

I need to open an existing xlsx file and write two data frames to specific cells then save this workbook as same name. I succeeded by this way before but this time it didn't work anymore. Code is running and no error message. But i don't see any changes to the existing excel file.

Here is my code:

```
library(XLConnect)
filename<-paste("A",paste0("Report_",Sys.Date(),".xlsx"))
path<- 'D:/Test/'  

# open template
wb2<-loadWorkbook(paste0(path,filename))

#call function user defined graph_r and get data
#agydf is used to call function graph_r 
tb<- ra_graph(agydf)

#write to excel sheet
writeWorksheet(wb2, tb[[1]], sheet = 'Graph', startRow = 6, 
startCol = 1)
writeWorksheet(wb2, tb[[2]], sheet = 'Graph', startRow = 40, 
startCol = 1)

saveWorkbook(wb2, filename)
```

Comment: You don't say how you assessed the lack of change. Did you close the viewer app and restart?

Comment: Before method writeworksheet everything works perfect. It might be issue of saveworkbook method because date modified of xlsx file didn't change. I restarted but still not working

Comment: I tried create a new workbook and worksheet then write two tables to new xlsx file and it worked.

Comment: I can't do changes to existing file

Comment: Files are often write-protect by the "other app" if they are kept open.

Comment: Got the problem. I don't know why i didn't get error before but when I rerun it again and got an error message                               
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: You may want to increase JVM max heap size via `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g")`. It is important to do that before XLConnect (or any other rJava-based package) is loaded.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work. I used package openxlsx instead. Thank you both for answering my question!